# How to find sequential equilibria and weak perfect bayesian equilibria quickly?

Tags: reference-request, game-theory

I have read several texts on the nature of sequential equilibria and weak perfect bayesian equilibria (called such by Mas-Colell, also called weak sequential equilibria).

I am not looking for computational methods that can be used by computers. I'm looking for a method to quickly find these equilibria in simple games that can be done by hand.

Could you recommend a good text that explains how to do this quickly?